# Displaying Objects in an Array VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So I am using a `JSON` object that looks something like this:

```
data: [
  {
    title: "Post Title One",
    categories: {
      data: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Category Name 1"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    title: "Post Title Two",
    categories: {
      data: [
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Category Name 1"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Category Name 2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

and I want to grab all the categories for each post and display them using Vue. So what I have currently is:

```
<div v-for="post in posts">
   <div>{{ post.categories.data }}</div>
</div>
```

In that `{{ post.categories.data }}` I am trying to display the category name from the `JSON` object. When I use what I have above the whole array is displayed in the div. When I try to do something like

```
{{ post.categories.data.name }}
```

or

```
{{ post.categories.data[0].name }}
```

I don't display the name of the category. I would really like to display the name of every category a post has, but can't seem to get it to display correctly.

EDIT: Also posts is the data property I am using in `VueJS` and am setting the `JSON` object to become that property.

Comment: Did you try "post.categories.data.map(d => d.name).join()" ? This will display all category names together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `map` method in conbination with *destructuring*.

```
<div v-for="post in posts">
    <div>{{ post.categories.data.map(({name}) => name).join(' ') }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That did the trick, Thanks! I am going to look more into the map method